# How to switch Rails database without having to do migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migration, backup

I have a Rails app which uses db `my_database_development` in my `config/database.yml`:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_database_development
```

Works correctly when I run `rails server`.

Now I want to use another db, so I change my `config/database.yml`:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_prev_database
```

Now when I run `rails server`, they give me an `ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`. When I run that command, `my_prev_database` gets cleared. I don't want that to happen. I want to use `my_prev_database` and all the data it has (which I backed up from somewhere)

How can I switch database in Rails effectively?

Thank you!

Comment: Is `my_prev_database` a database that has the same tables as the current Rails application?

Comment: The `ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError` basically means that your database is not in sync with the current state of your application and might not be compatible. Why do you want to use that database with your application? Is it an option to check out an older version of your application that matches the database version? This sounds like a cy problem to me.

Comment: Running migrations will not delete data. Unless the migration itself deletes the data. And you cannot switch to an alternative database that's in a different state - i.e. is not up to date with the most recent migrations.

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that `my_prev_database` has all the exact rows and tables needed by the rails app

Comment: @spickermann The application version is exactly the same. I used to run my Rails app on heroku. And now I'm transferring the app to AWS. So I cloned my app to AWS. Now I downloaded a pg dump from Heroku and want to use it in AWS.

Comment: @TomLord hmm, hmm alright, perhaps the migrations delete the data somehow Will have to check...

The database can actually be exactly the same, and switching database still gives migration errors.
Here's how to replicate:
1) Run rails server with `my_db_dev`
2) Duplicate `my_db_dev` exactly to another `my_db_copy`
3) Switch Rails config to use `my_db_copy`. Get migration error.

And no, I didn't copy `my_db_copy` wrongly. I can actually have another instance of my Rails app use `my_db_copy` originally and that works. But switch it to `my_db_dev` and I'll get migration errors.

Comment: If the application version was exactly the same how do you explain the `PendingMigrationError`? That error means there is a migration in your application that is not present in the `schema_migrations` table of the database. Why is that entry missing?

Comment: Which migration(s) does it say needs to be run? What migration(s) exist in the `schema_migrations` table? How are you duplicating `my_db_dev`? What is different about the "other instance of the app that's using the copy"?... Is that *after* you ran migrations?

Comment: @spickermann @TomLord Thanks a lot for your help! For some reason, I am now unable to replicate the problem, after having the problem since yesterday. If you want to know, `schema_migrations` has 30 entries for all the databases I duplicated.

I still don't know what caused `PendingMigrationError` previously

Comment: My theory is that I probably did not copy my database properly.

Answer (score 1):

When you switch database, you will have new `schema_migrations` table. In new database, `schema_migrations` is empty so Rails will think you have `pending_migration`. I think you need to re-migrate in your new database. You can use some feature like database dump to migrate date from old database to new database

Answer (score 0):

I am now unable to replicate the problem above. (Not sure why, maybe I was copying over my database incorrectly.)

Also, a possible resolution was to copy tables over individually from `my_prev_database` to `my_database_development`

Note for anyone troubleshooting similar problems:
The commenters mentioned that,
 - Running `rails db:migrate` shouldn't delete database data